# Uncaught ReferenceError: route is not defined in Laravel 8

Tags: javascript, vue.js, laravel-8

```
require('./bootstrap');
require('./ziggy');
window.Vue = require('vue');
const files = require.context('./', true, /\.vue$/i);
files.keys().map(key => {
    return Vue.component(_.last(key.split('/')).split('.')[0], files(key))
});
const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
})
Vue.mixin({
    methods: {
        route: route
    }
});
```

After installing Laravel 8 authentication, I get this error in the console.

> app.js:63273 Uncaught ReferenceError: route is not defined
> at Module../resources/js/app.js (app.js:63273)
> at webpack_require (app.js:20)
> at Object.0 (app.js:63334)
> at webpack_require (app.js:20)
> at app.js:84
> at app.js:87 app.js:58049

Download the Vue Devtools extension for better development. Due to this, my JavaScript is not working properly. I have to hit the URL for an auth module.

Comment: app.js:63273 Uncaught ReferenceError: route is not defined
    at Module../resources/js/app.js (app.js:63273)
    at __webpack_require__ (app.js:20)
    at Object.0 (app.js:63334)
    at __webpack_require__ (app.js:20)
    at app.js:84
    at app.js:87
app.js:58049 Download the Vue Devtools extension for a better development

Comment: error in console

Comment: What does `require.context` return? You should use square brackets if it returns an array: `files[key]`

Comment: By the way, I've added the error to the question if you want to remove your comments

Comment: What is the route  is the equalivant to ? I dont see anything to assign route.

Comment: Also, `route` isn't declared anywhere

Answer (score 0):

in your Root Template (defaults to app.blade.php) ([details here](https://inertiajs.com/server-side-setup)), add

```
@routes
```

before the line that calls app.js

Answer (score -1):

It happens because of this code. You didnt declare `route` variable. Because of that it throws error.

```
Vue.mixin({
methods: {
    route: route
}
});
```

Comment: where I have to declare kindly provide the sample code